# Como receber dois dados em uma listview mas apresentar apenas um e utilizar o outro no click?

Tags: android, listview

Tenho uma listview onde listo o nome de pessoas e quando clico em uma pessoa uso o `adapter.getitem(position)` que pega o nome da pessoa, porém, eu precisava pegar o id da pessoa e não o nome. Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso? Resumidamente eu preciso trazer 2 dados do banco, o nome e o id, porém apresentar apenas o nome na listView e pegar o id quando clicar. há nomes semelhantes, por isso preciso do id.

obs: Atualmente estou fazendo uma coisa que não sei se é gambiarra ou é inteligente. listo os nomes e quando clico no nome usa a opção para pegar o id. Por enquanto está funcionando mas não é uma boa prática.

Comment: Como vc está populando o adapter da listview?

Comment: Estou utlizando um ArrayAdapter, eu recebo um vetor com os nomes do banco e coloco nele.

Comment: Pessoa é uma entidade(classe) com id e nome? Você está passando um Array de Pessoas pro seu listview? Adicione mais informações, sem saber isso que questionei fica dificil ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Quando fizer a consulta para pegar os nomes e popular a listview, crie um [ArrayList](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html) e popule ele com os ids dos nomes.

No evento OnClick do listview, você pode retornar o id do nome clicado assim:

```
seuListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {

   //retornando o id do nome clicado a partir do ArrayList já populado
   String id= arrayDeId.get(position);

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá

Você pode criar um CustomAdapter para sua ListView utilizando um BaseAdapter. Com ele criado, vc pode adicionar cada entidade de Pessoa e no click da listview recuperar apenas o ID da pessoa. [Aqui](https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/custom-baseadapters/) tem um exemplo de como criar um custom com BaseAdapter.

Espero ter ajudado, qualquer dúvida deixe um comentário.